# Can a edge in cytoscape have multiple colors

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am trying to create a edge with multiple colors, not sure how to go about it.
Ideally each half of the link would have their color updated independently.

Want to know if this is feasible.
Thanks a lot
:)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is! Check https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-line and https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/gradient.

The strategy would be to break the line-gradient into color-stop positions, each with an associated color like this:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        "label": "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "line-fill": "radial-gradient",
        "line-gradient-stop-colors": "red green blue",
        "line-gradient-stop-positions": "25 50 75"
      }
    }
  ],
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "a",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "b",
          faveColor: "#37a32d"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "c",
          faveColor: "#37a32d"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "a",
          target: "b"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "a",
          target: "c"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    name: "dagre"
  }
}));

cy.ready(function() {
  cy.dblclick();
});

var nid = 0;
cy.bind('dblclick', function(evt) {
  console.log('dblclick');
  cy.add({
    group: 'nodes',
    data: {
      id: nid,
      faveColor: 'red'
    },
    position: {
      x: evt.x,
      y: evt.y
    }
  });
  nid++;
});

cy.bind('click', 'node', function(evt) {
  console.log('node clicked: ', evt.target.id());
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-dblclick/dist/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```